# validation on new leads inserted with apex method

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, duplicate-management

1. How do I validate, when a collection of new leads would create duplicates in the system and return segregated lists in a map (when its True: list of non-duplicates and when its False: list of duplicates)
2. I would recognize duplicate lead by its email and company

Code:

```
public with sharing class leadDuplicate {
    public static Map<Boolean, List<Lead>> leadDupCheck (List<Lead> newL){
        Map<Boolean, List<Lead>> leadResults = leadDuplicateCheck(newL);
        return leadResults;

    }
    public static List<Lead> getNewLeads(){
        List<Lead> newLead = [SELECT Email, Company FROM Lead];
        return newLead;
    } 
    public static void leadCheck (List<Lead> newLeads){
        List<Lead> newlds = getNewLeads();
        Map<Boolean, List<Lead>> leadMap = new Map<Boolean, List<Lead>>();
        for(Lead l : newlds){
            if(l.email != NULL || l.company != NULL){
                Lead[] leads = [select email,company from Lead where id in: newLeads];
                if(leads.size()>0){
                    leadMap.put(false,newlds);
                    system.debug('leadMap'+leadMap);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the specific problem you're struggling with in this code. See [ask] for more about what we need to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using out-of-the-box Duplicate Management?

Comment: Yes,That didn't work for my requirement ,Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to query the existing leads by email and company in order to identify potential duplicates. Here's one possible solution:

```
public static Map<Boolean, Lead[]> leadCheck(Lead[] newLeads) {
  // true => non-duplicate lead, false => duplicate lead
  Map<Boolean, Lead[]> results = new Map<Boolean, Lead[]> {
    false => new Lead[0], true => new Lead[0] 
  };
  Set<Lead> existingLeads = new Set<Lead>();
  {
    // Get all new emails and company names
    Set<String> email = new Set<String>, company = new Set<String>();
    for(Lead record: newLeads) {
      email.add(record.Email);
      company.add(record.Company);
    }
    // But ignore null values
    email.remove(null);
    company.remove(null);
    // Build a set of existing records from the database
    for(Lead oldLead:[SELECT Email,Company FROM Lead WHERE Email = :email AND Company = :company]) {
      existingLeads.add(new Lead(Email = oldLead.Email.toLowerCase(), Company = oldLead.Company.toLowerCase()));
    }
  }
  for(Lead newLead: newLeads) { 
    // Build a "key" to search in the Set.
    String email = newLead.Email != null? newLead.Email: '';
    String company = newLead.Company != null? newLead.Company: '';
    email = email.toLowerCase();
    company = company.toLowerCase();
    Lead key = new Lead(Email = email, Company = Company);
    // if set.contains is true, this is a duplicate record
    // We invert the result to match problem statement
    results.get(!existingLeads.contains(key)).add(newLead);
    // Also, add record to duplicate Set to check for duplicate incoming leads
    if(email != '' && company != '') {
      existingLeads.add(key);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: I was unable to check for duplicated in the above code, i tried debugging but no luck 
Thanks alot sfdcfox!